# Ubuntu 16: google-chrome-stable : Depends: libappindicator1 but it is not going to be installed

Tags: apt, software-installation, 16.04

I installed Ubuntu 16 desktop a few weeks ago. Added Chrome and all fine. However now when I try `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`, I get this error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 google-chrome-stable : Depends: libappindicator1 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

What's the problem and what should I do?

Comment: What happens when you run `sudo apt-get -f install`, as suggested by the error message?

Comment: Also, do you get any errors with `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: @nick I am typically wary of resorting to `-f` commands before I am sure I fathom all the implications. No errors in for `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: Well you have some unresolved dependencies that need to be resolved somehow. If you really don't want to run `sudo apt-get -f install`, you'll need to use Aptitude, Synaptic, or another package-management tool to resolve the dependency issues.

Comment: @matt I think I understand your concern but fear not, `-f` in the context of `apt-get` doesn't mean 'force', but it's short for `--fix-broken`. From `man apt-get`: "Fix; attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place". You can safely run `sudo apt-get install -f`.

Comment: @NickWeinberg I followed your advice, and it solved the issue and got the package I was trying to install installed. Care to make it the answer? I am clueless how I got to broken dependencies in a few weeks' old 16.04 installation that has gone nearly zero tinkering, but the `apt-get install -f` managed to fix it. Hopefully it had not also left ugly surprises for later....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can run `sudo apt-get -f install`, as suggested by the error message. This should install any needed dependencies and resolve the issue. (Alternatively, you could use Synaptic, Aptitude, or another package manager to resolve the dependency issue.)

As @grooveplex pointed out, the `-f` stands for `--fix-broken`, not "force", and should not cause any damage to your system.

Answer (score 0):

Google chrome is not available from Ubuntu repository, instead setup is downloaded from Google's servers.. you should be able to install `libappindicator1` using `sudo apt install libappindicator1` (it's in the 16.04 repository) or from synaptic package manager, and then try installing the `chrome.deb`

[image: Synaptic Package Manager : 1.search for libappindicator1, 2.Mark for Installation, 3.Apply]

If you do not have synaptic

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Once the libappindicator1 is in place, Open the `.deb` in Ubuntu Software Install as shown on Google Chrome's download page

Comment: You might be able to be more elaborate on how to install it. At the current state this is more a comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me with installing `libappindicator1` on Ubuntu and in Docker as well - is installing this package manually. Also, it depends on another one `libindicator7`.

```
RUN curl -p --insecure "http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/liba/libappindicator/libappindicator1_12.10.1+18.04.20180322.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb" --output libappindicator1_0.4.92-8_amd64.deb \
    && curl -p --insecure "http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libi/libindicator/libindicator7_16.10.0+18.04.20180321.1-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb" --output libindicator7_0.5.0-4_amd64.deb \
    && dpkg -i libindicator7_0.5.0-4_amd64.deb \
    && dpkg -i libappindicator1_0.4.92-8_amd64.deb \
    && rm libindicator7_0.5.0-4_amd64.deb \
    && rm libappindicator1_0.4.92-8_amd64.deb
```